Celery shared_task not working with pytest in fastapi
I am struggling to test fastapi endpoint that contains a celery task. I would like to mock the celery task. The task is as follows
send_email.delay(
        user.email,
        "Subject goes here",
        html_content,
    )

Here is how the actual mock function
@pytest.fixture
def mocked_send_email(mocker):
    mocker.patch('app.views.user.send_email.delay', return_value=None)

def test_create_user(client, mocked_send_email):

    payload = {}

    response = client.post(
        f"{base_url}/user",
        json=payload,
        headers=admin_headers
    )

    mocked_send_email.assert_called_once_with(
        "email@example.com",
        "Subject goes here",
        mock.ANY
    )

Here is my part of conftest.py that handles celery
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    print('running celery config')
    return {"broker_url": REDIS, "result_backend": REDIS}


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def configure_celery(celery_config):
    from app.celery import celery
    celery.conf.update(celery_config)
    yield
    celery.conf.update({
        'broker_url': 'memory://',
        'result_backend': 'rpc://'
    })

Now when i run my test, I get the following error
usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kombu/connection.py:476: OperationalError
test_1           | ------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
test_1           | WARNING  kombu.connection:connection.py:669 _info - _info - No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'

My setup is dockerized and running with no errors when I am not running pytest. I am really stumped here and I am not sure whats causing this error considering my setup looks good and works when i am not running tests.Any help will be very much appreciated
Update. Print statements for configure celery fixture
Before update:redis://redis-cache:6379/1 redis://redis-cache:6379/1
After update:redis://redis-cache:6379/5 redis://redis-cache:6379/5
After reset: memory:// rpc://


what is the value of REDIS. Maybe add print(celery_config) somewhere to make sure the value is passed correctly

REDIS is properly set. Thats the redis url from env

ok. Well I am not sure what the issue is, but I would suggest using pytest-celery https://pypi.org/project/pytest-celery/. That's what I use for running tests that depend on a mocked celery, or a testing celery broker/backend.

it's the official celery plugin for pytest:
https://docs.celeryq.dev/projects/pytest-celery/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

try to add print statements to the configure_celery() function to check if celery.conf.broker_url is being updated correctly:
print("Before update:", celery.conf.broker_url, celery.conf.result_backend)
then after update:
print("After update:", celery.conf.broker_url, celery.conf.result_backend)
then after reset:
print("After reset:", celery.conf.broker_url, celery.conf.result_backend)

I have updated the question @Ouss. Unless I am missing something this looks okay? Why then is it failing

Btw i noticed that when i decorate the actual celery task with celery_app instance instead of shared_task the error goes away. Is there some config I am missing?

Could you please add that detail to the question, with the code snipet? I am sure it will be useful for others to answer.

The error that I encountered seems to be stemming from my usage of@shared_task decorator. Based on the Celery documentation for Django here, using @shared_task requires additional configuration. Since I'm using FastAPI, I am not sure how to incorporate this configuration into my project.
To resolve this, I have switched from using @shared_task to directly using the Celery application instance with @celery_app.task. I don't like this approach much. But it's currently wprking for me. I'm open to any solutions that better align with Django's Celery configuration.
If anyone has insights on properly configuring @shared_task in a FastAPI project or a more elegant solution, I would appreciate your input.
Update
I finally figured out the most appropriate way to setup a fastapi application to properly use celery's shared_task thanks to this blog post
First you need to configure your celery.py as follows. Notice that instead of creating new Celery instance, we are using current_app so that shared_task will work as expected
from celery import Celery, current_app as current_celery_app
def make_celery(app_name=__name__):
    # Use the current Celery app instance if it exists, otherwise create a new one
    celery = current_celery_app if current_celery_app else Celery(app_name)

    celery.conf.update(
        broker='redis://localhost:6379/1',  # Specify the broker URL
        backend='redis://localhost:6379/1',  # Specify the result backend
    )

    return celery


celery_app = make_celery()

You will then need to setup your main.py as follows. Notice we are using factory pattern approach which ensures Fastapi application is correctly setup with Celery
def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    @asynccontextmanager
    async def app_lifespan(app: FastAPI):
        app.celery = make_celery()
        yield

    app = FastAPI(lifespan=app_lifespan)

   

    @app.get("/")
    async def root():
        return {"message": "Welcome to the FastAPI application"}

    return app


app = create_app()

By following this setup, you can effectively use @shared_task in your FastAPI project, ensuring that Celery tasks are correctly registered and managed, similar to how it works in a Django project. It’s surprising that the Celery team hasn't provided clear documentation on this integration, but this approach should help you get up and running smoothly.
